# Unity(2020.1.5f1) Intellisense not working on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

I created and loaded up a script via unity, however it has disabled intellisense.

I have the external script editor on unity set to visual studio, and have regenerate all the project files, as shown in the screenshot

[image: here].

I have also got the unity addon installed and running on visual studio, however intellisense is still not working.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Can you make a screenshot to prove intellisense is not working? Is intellisense disabled in settings? Also check [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1693761/cant-get-unity-intelisense-to-work-in-visual-studi.html).

Comment: I have visual studio set as the script editor in unity and it still doesn't work [here](https://imgur.com/a/lC3VnHX)

Comment: Do you miss [`using` directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)? Define *not working*? What do you expect exactly to happens?

Comment: Before it would auto complete it to Gameobject etc. however after loading up a new script it has stopped doing it. It is not the using directives as it ha stopped on all scripts, even ones it previously worked on.